# Creating A WordPress Product Page Template

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Happy Saturday everyone.

I want to create a product page like this for my Wordpress theme. But I'm new to WordPress. All I know right now is, I should probably create a post template because I want to make product publishing easier and I will load posts list based on category.

However, if I use a post template, how am I gonna publish the product content? By that I specifically mean how am I going to separate them when I'm posting and how am I going to get them and load them in their corresponding blocks (e.g. load only the images I decide to use as product presentation in the carousel). Obviously I don't want to write extra html tags when I'm posting a new product, because that's not the point of CMS. (Maybe it's still necessary sometimes :/) Or Maybe I can use Javascript to restructure the content of the post when it's loaded?
Am I talking about creating a dedicated Wordpress plug-in?

Please give me some clue or any source I should look into. THANKS!

[image: my product page]

Comment: Your question is not very specific. Is there anything that you have tried so far? Which problems occured? In general, you may want to look at some e-commerce-related plugins for Wordpress, e.g. http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/

Comment: If you don't want to use an e-commerce plugin, you could [create your own post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and then use a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to provide additional fields in a structured way to your theme.